# Repeat headers at bottom of reStructuredText table

Tags: tabular, restructuredtext

I have a simple table like this:

```
======= ========= ===========
header  header1   header2
======= ========= ===========
line1   line1a    line1b
line2   line2a    line2b
line3   line3a    line3b
line4   line4a    line4b
line5   line5a    line5b
======= ========= ===========
```

But the table is getting pretty long, so I'm wondering whether its possible to get the headers to repeat at the bottom. Doing simply the following does not work:

```
======= ========= ===========
header  header1   header2
======= ========= ===========
line1   line1a    line1b
line2   line2a    line2b
line3   line3a    line3b
line4   line4a    line4b
line5   line5a    line5b
======= ========= ===========
header  header1   header2
======= ========= ===========
```